# swagger ui for Map attribute in Jax-Rs Jersey application

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

How to specify the swagger documentation annotation for generating model schema for Map attribute in a Java bean?

```
//groovy code
class Foo {
  int id
  String description
  Map<String, Bar> targets
  //few other attributes
}
```

For `targets` attribute, swaggerui shows 1 line but does not give the model schema for `Bar` class.

```
    targets (Map[string,Bar])
```

How do I get `Bar` class Model schema as well in UI?